# Move data from legacy app to new rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, database-migration

I am in the process of transferring data from legacy rails app to a new rails app. Both use devise for authentication. Is there a way to migrate  users encrypted_passwords?

Answer (score 0):

It's no problem to just copy over the data from your `users` table as long as you use the same `Rails.application.secret_key_base` as the old application.

In case you want to use a different secret key base, then there is no easy way to migrate the data.

A possible approach would be to override the code that checks the password, using the old secret key base, then immediately save the password with the new secret key base.